# Plasma behavior around the Electric spark in air

Tags: electrons, ions

When a pointed cathode and a plane anode are subjected high voltage dc and there is air between them, and spark is formed and the spark is allowed to sustain for few micro seconds, how the electrons and ions of gas will move in the plasma formed(the path of electrons and ions in plasma)?